# How to declare a instance variable of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this generic class:

```
public abstract class FilterPage<T> where T : IResponse 
{
     protected List<T> apiResults;
     public abstract List<T> Post();
}
```

And this class that inherites from FilterPage:

```
public class ExportImportPage : FilterPage<DemandExportReport>
{
     public override List<DemandExportReport> Post()
     {
            return apiResults = API.Post<List<DemandExportReport>>(FilterReqtUrl);
     }
}

public class DemandExportReport : IResponse
{
     ...
}
```

And here I have the class where I am doing my initializations:

```
class TestClass
{
     public void Method1()
     {    
          FilterPage<DemandExportReport> myInst = new ExportImportPage();
     }

     public void Method2()
     {
         // I want to use myInst here.
     }

}
```

In TestClass, if I declare and initialize `myInst` in `Method1()` as `FilterPage<DemandExportReport> myInst = new ExportImportPage()`, it works fine. My problem is that I don't know the type at compile time. Instead of `DemandExportReport` I may use a different type. I want to initialize myInst in `Method1()` and then use it in other methods, being able to call `myInst.Post()`. So, how can I declare `myInst` without doing `FilterPage<DemandExportReport> myInst;`, as I want to use several types with `FilterPage` instead of `DemandExportReport`?

**Note:** If I create a non-generic base class, let's say `BaseFilterPage`, and then inherite `FilterPage<t>` from it, I am able to declare a `BaseFilterPage` instance class. The problem is that with that variable I don't have access to the `Post()` method. And I cannot move the `Post()` declaration to `BaseFilterPage` because it is a generic method.

Comment: *"My problem is that I don't know the type at compile time."* -- then you can't use generics.

Comment: @EdPlunkett well, you *can*, but unless you're a library author, you probably shouldn't - most app code should know the T; doing it without knowing the type at compile-time is an ugly mess of reflection etc

Comment: I agree with the other comments, you shouldn't try to use generics if you don't know the type at compile time

Comment: If you don't know what `T` is at compile time, what good does it do to get a `List<T>` from your method? You could as well return an `IEnumerable<Object>` and put it in the non-generic interface.

Comment: If what you really mean is that Method1 doesn't know the type parameter at compile time, but you will be calling Method1 from multiple places where the type parameter *is* known at compile time, you can write a non-generic base and make Method1 generic: `Method1<T>() { var myInst = new FilterPage<T>(); /* ... */ }`. Then call `Method1<DemandExportReport>();` in the other code that knows it wants `DemandExportReport` to be the type parameter.

Comment: Not only is this true - "you shouldn't try to use generics if you don't know the type at compile time", but you should also try very, very hard to always know the type at compile time. If we don't, not being able to use generics is only one of many problems.

Comment: It's not clear from your question or code example what would actually be valid. I do agree with comments saying if you don't know the type at compile time, then a generic solution doesn't seem appropriate. But your question doesn't preclude the caller of `Method2()` from knowing the type. @Ed's response hints at this, but he's focusing on `Method1()`, which doesn't seem in line with your question. Instead, I'd focus on `Method2()`, which if you make generic then could do what you want. Specifically: `void Method2<T>(FilterPage<T> myInst) where T : IResponse { myInst.Post(); }` would work.